# How do I split an array into two different arrays?

Tags: c#

I can't seem to figure out how to fix my code so that it works. I need the user to be able to input their first name then space then the what they scored. Then I need to split the array into two different arrays and pass them to the four different methods to display to the user what they scored, etc. Can anyone help me figure this problem out?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace proj09LEA
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // declare and array of integers
            int[] array = new int[10];

            Console.WriteLine("\nSaturday Coder's Bowling Team");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in a name and score for each person on the team.");
            Console.WriteLine("For example, Mary 143. Just hit Enter when you are done.\n");

            // fill an array with user input
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter in a name and score: ");
                string userInput;
                string[] parsedInput;
                parsedInput = userInput.Split();
                string name = parsedInput[0];
                int score = int.Parse(parsedInput[1]);

            }

            Console.WriteLine("------------ Input Complete ------------\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Here are the scores for this game:");

            DisplayScore(array);
            HighScore(array);
            LowScore(array);
            AverageScore(array);

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue. . .");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void DisplayScore(int[] array)
        {
            foreach (int n in array)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}'s score was {0}.\n", array);
            }
        }

        static void HighScore(int[] array)
        {
            int max = array.Max();
            Console.WriteLine("Congratulations {0}, your score of {0} was the highest.", max);
        }

        static void LowScore(int[] array)
        {
            int min = array.Min();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, your score of {0} was the lowest. Better get some practice.", min);
        }

        static void AverageScore(int[] array)
        {
            int sum = array.Sum();
            int average = sum / array.Length;
            Console.WriteLine("The average score for this game was {0:d}.", average);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use simple arrays, or are you allowed to use collections of classes or tuples?

Comment: probably just simple arrays. or whatever way is easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely have to use simple primitive arrays, you would need two distinct arrays of the same size, to hold the names as strings and scores as ints:

```
class Program
{
    const int MaxScores = 10;  // .. Use a constant to ensure the sizes remain in sync
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { ///
        string[] names = new int[MaxScores];
        int[] scores = new int[MaxScores];
        // ... parse names into names[] and scores into scores[]

        DisplayScore(names, scores);
```

You would then need to pass both arrays to the various methods:

```
static void DisplayScore(string[] names, int[] scores)
{
   for(int i=0; i < MaxScores; i++)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("{0}'s score was {1}.\n", names[i], scores[i]);
   }
}
// etc
```

However, there are better ways to do this, e.g. by defining a custom class for the tuple of `Name, Score`:

```
class PersonScore
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Score {get; set;}
}
```

You can then declare and pass the single array of `PersonScore[]` around.

```
PersonScore[] personScores = new PersonScore[MaxScores];
for (... prompting the user for data) 
{
   ... parsing user input
   personScores[i] = new PersonScore{Name = name, Score = score};
}
DisplayScore(personScores); // Pass around the single array

static void DisplayScore(IEnumerable personScores)
{
   foreach(var personScore in personScores)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("{0}'s score was {1}.\n", personScore.Name, personScores.Score);
   }
}
// etc - other methods
```

As others have mentioned, other collections are also possible alternatives to an array, most commonly `List`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. Just use Console.ReadLine() to get user input. This is what you do in your code. There are better ways to do this but following will solve your problem.Also you need to perform validation as well.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter in a name and score: ");
                string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                string[] parsedInput;
                parsedInput = userInput.Split(' ');
                string name = parsedInput[0];
                int score = int.Parse(parsedInput[1]);
                array[i] = score;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to split array in to two arrays on containing names and other containing score. Its better to create a structure having String field for name and integer field for score and write Comparator for sorting the Array containing elements of this Data structure type and sort them.

It will solve all your problems and that too efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Not many data integrity checks in the methods you are using, but here are the extensions I use to split arrays or any type of enumerable.  I have not tested these all that much, so I cannot guarantee that they will work.  I have removed all my input validation, but I suggest you add those back your own way.

```
    public static List<List<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Int32 groupSize)
    {
        var collectionList = collection.ToList();
        if (groupSize > collectionList.Count)
            groupSize = collectionList.Count;

        var chunks = new List<List<T>>();
        while (collectionList.Any())
        {
            var chunk = collectionList.Take(groupSize);
            chunks.Add(chunk.ToList());
            collectionList = collectionList.Skip(groupSize).ToList();
        }

        return chunks;
    }

    public static List<List<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, Boolean> splitFunction)
    {
        var collectionList = collection.ToList();

        if (collectionList.IsNullOrEmpty())
            return new List<List<T>>();
        var indices = collectionList.FindIndices(splitFunction); // Custom method that searches for the indices that satisfy the predicate and returns the index of each matching item in the list.
        if (indices.IsNullOrEmpty()) // equivalent to indices == null || !indices.Any()
            return new List<List<T>> { collectionList };

        var chunks = new List<List<T>>();
        var lastIndex = 0;
        if (indices[0] > 0)
        {
            chunks.Add(collectionList.Take(indices[0]).ToList());
            lastIndex = indices[0];
        }

        for (var i = 1; i < indices.Count; i++)
        {
            var chunkSize = indices[i] - lastIndex;
            var chunk = collectionList.Skip(lastIndex).Take(chunkSize).ToList();
            if (chunk.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                break;
            }
            chunks.Add(chunk);
            lastIndex = indices[i];
        }

        if (collectionList.Count - lastIndex > 0)
        {
            var lastChunk = collectionList.Skip(lastIndex).ToList();
            chunks.Add(lastChunk);
        }

        return chunks;
    }
```

Comment: call me a newb... but im seriously confused. where do i insert the code for fixing this problem and what do i need to fix?

Comment: The methods I posted are extensions, and will have to put in a separate class.  Or you can remove the 'this' from the parameter so you can use it in the same class.